# VB 2019 OleDb: Insert new record fails

Tags: vb.net, insert, oledb

This procedure records when users log into or out of the application.  Its sole purpose is to write five values to a single new record.  Please note that I want to minimize SQL coding.

The .Update method throws this error:
DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection property needs to be initialized;'

How do I solve this?  Is there anything else I should be doing?

' Visual Basic 2019. The database was created in Access 2019.
' Target CPU has been set to x64.
' In Manage NuGet I have added system.data.oledb, version 6.00.
' I added the reference for "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library"

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Public Sub RecordUserLogEvent(blnLoggingIn As Boolean)
        Dim cmdEventLogs As OleDbCommand
        Dim odaEventLogs As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dtEventLogs As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dim cmEventLogsManager As CurrencyManager
        cmdEventLogs = New OleDbCommand() 
        odaEventLogs = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        odaEventLogs.SelectCommand = cmdEventLogs
        dtEventLogs = New DataTable()
        cmEventLogsManager = DirectCast(Me.BindingContext(dtEventLogs), CurrencyManager)
        cmEventLogsManager.AddNew()
        cmEventLogsManager.Position = 1
        dtEventLogs.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MACaddress", GetType(String)))
        dtEventLogs.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("UserID", GetType(String)))
        dtEventLogs.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("IPaddress", GetType(String)))
        dtEventLogs.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("When", GetType(Date)))
        dtEventLogs.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("LoggedIn", GetType(Boolean)))
        With frmMain
            dtEventLogs.Rows(0).Item("MACaddress") = .strMACaddress
            dtEventLogs.Rows(0).Item("UserID") = .strUserID
            dtEventLogs.Rows(0).Item("IPaddress") = .strIPaddress
            dtEventLogs.Rows(0).Item("When") = Now()
            dtEventLogs.Rows(0).Item("LoggedIn") = blnLoggingIn
        End With
        cmEventLogsManager.EndCurrentEdit()
        cmEventLogsManager.Position = 0  ' Move so that tabe data flushes
        Dim odaEventLogsCommands As New OleDbCommandBuilder(odaEventLogs)
        Debug.Print("Insert command:" + odaEventLogsCommands.GetInsertCommand.CommandText)
        odaEventLogs.Update(dtEventLogs)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I also expect you're missing the `InsertCommand` for the dataadapter, but either way you have to connect to the database:

```
cmdEventLogs.Connection = New OleDbConnection("connection string here")
cmdEventLogs.Connection.Open()
```

You probably already have the connection string elsewhere in the application, but if you need help finding it, look here:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2013/

Note the Access 2013 syntax is still correct for 2019. Also note: this is a case where writing a little SQL would actually save you a lot of trouble and significantly reduce the amount of code you need to write: no datatable or columns, no dataadapter.

```vb
Public Sub RecordUserLogEvent(blnLoggingIn As Boolean)
    Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO EventLogs (MACAddress, UserID, IPAddress, When, LoggedIn) VALUES (?, ?, ?, Date(), ?);"

    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("MACAddress", OleDbType.Char, 17).Value = frmMain.strMACaddress
        cmd.Parameters.Add("UserID", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = frmMain.strUserId
        cmd.Parameters.Add("IPAddresss", OleDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = frmMain.strIPaddress
        cmd.Parameters.Add("LoggedIn", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = blnLogginIn

        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() throws this error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement".  The cmd.CommandText is "INSERT INTO tblUserLogEvents (MACaddress,UserID,IPaddress,When,LoggedIn) VALUES (?,?,?,Date(),?)". What are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

First up, do NOT reference active data objects (WHY WHY WHY???)

next up, WHY are you forcing project to x64 bits? I mean, you MIGHT have a good reason, but it has to be MORE then just throwing mud against the wall!!!!

And why ARE you adding a newget package for oledb? It is native to the system.

If you are running + using access x32 on that computer, then you need to force and set your project to x32 (x86). However, if you have Access/office x64 installed, then you need to force/set your project to x64.

Next up, how are you building the connection string?

Assuming you fixed all of above?

Then your code can look like this:

```
Public Sub RecordUserLogEvent(blnLoggingIn As Boolean)

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblLogs WHERE ID = 0"

    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            Dim MyNewRow As DataRow = rstData.NewRow

            With frmMain
                MyNewRow("MACaddress") = .strMACaddress.Text
                MyNewRow("UserID") = .strUserID.Text
                MyNewRow("IPaddress") = .strIPaddress.Text
                MyNewRow("When") = Now()
                MyNewRow("LoggedIn") = blnLoggingIn
            End With
            rstData.Rows.Add(MyNewRow)
            ' save to database
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

So, first up, your connection.

I suggest you go from menu Project->Project name properties

[image]

Now, settings.

[image]

So, now you can use that setting in code.

So, the bit size setting of your project has to match the version of Access installed (x32 or x64).

## Edit: Follow up based on comments

> conn.Open() I changed your table name tglLogs to my tblUserLogEvents da.Update(rstData)

Excellent. Remember, this is "air code" on my part. (but GREAT catch).

Yes, you need a open command, so this:

```
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
```

> INSERT INTO statement.'

No, you JUST use:

```
 Dim strSQL As String =
    "SELECT * FROM tblUserLogEvents WHERE ID = 0"
```

Above assumes your PK column is "ID". (which in "most" cases for ms-access is going to be id). You do NOT need, nor want, nor use a "insert" statement. So, in above, if your PK column is not "ID", then change "ID" to whatever your pk column is.

Once you used the above statement, then we "eventually" do this:

```
     rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
```

That loads + creates our data table (which is VERY much like a ADO recordset you used back in VB5-vb6 days). So, this creates our table, but one with no rows!!!

At that point, you can add rows to that pseudo table. You can add 1 row, or 10 rows. We do NOT require a sql insert command!!!

In fact, you could even use this:

```
    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblLogs WHERE ID <= 10"
```

That would load up our table with as many as 10 records (assuming id 1-10 existed. At that point, I can modify any row in the data table, I cna delete rows, or even add rows (as we are doing).

Once done, then edits, deletes, and inserts (as we are doing) can ALL be sent back to the database in ONE shot!!

Eg this code:

```
            rstData.Rows.Add(MyNewRow)
            ' save to database
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)
```

So, we created a "MyNewRow". We set the values, and then "add" to our table (which in our case has no rows, but the select * from table DOES create our correct table structure - despite returning no records!!!!

So, yes, you STILL use the above ONE statement (select * from mytable).

The "end result"? Well, then code that follows works NEAR identical to the ADO object you used in the past (and thus I SPECIFIC coded this example that way, taking that past history into account!!!).

and as the above approach shows, then we don't have to deal with messy and ugly insert statements (VERY much the reason why you probably used ADO in the past!!! - once you have that recordset, or now in .net land the data table, then we are free to make ANY updates to that data table, and thus edits, looping the table, or in our case adding a row?

Then the above bit of code "save to database" will automatic send any and all changes to that table BACK to the database. So, no, we do NOT require a sql insert statement. Once we have that data table (aka: like a ADO recordset) then we are free to add rows, edit rows, make changes to that datatable, and THEN send any and all changes (including inserts) back to the database.

> My Access 2019 is 64-bit, and I thought that 64-bit has been around long enough to be "mature

Yes, but given you taken cs?

then you would well grasp that that you can't run different processor architecture software with each other.

In other words, windows x64 bit code not going to run on a 8 bit apple II computer.

So, while for the last 10+ years, most (99%) of windows are now a x64 bit OS install? You are still able to run x32 bit software on that computer.

So, when you compile + build your project? You are given a choice to compile as "any cpu", or you can compile (force) the project to create x32 bit compiled output, or x64 bits.

so, if you using x64 bit Access, then you NEED to force/set/choose/make sure that your project is compiled to match the bit size of ms-access that you have installed. So, it not a question of "mature", it is the basic question of knowing there is a difference between compiling your .net project as x32 bits vs x64 bits.

Turns out, that prior to vs2022, then if you choose "any cpu" and whack f5 to compile + run your project? That would result in a x32 bit program.

However, vs2022 is the FIRST version of vs that is x64 bits!!!(yup, you read this correct!!! - all these years, vs been a x32 bit system. However, vs2022 is now a x64 bit program, and that means "any cpu" and whacking f5 to run will result in a x64 bit version of your software!!!

.net is different then say vb5/6 in that you can choose x32 or x64 bits, or the 3rd option of ANY cpu. If you choose ANY cpu, then depending on if you using windows command prompt (x32) or windows command prompt (x64) thus will determine what bit size your software runs as!!! (windows has 2 cmd.exe's - a x32 one, or a x64 one).

Now, if you using JUST .net code, then you probably don't care. However, since your code is interacting with ms-access data engine, then you MUST match up the bit size and and ensure that your compiled project matches the "library" code you are using - in this case ms-access.

> connection string was copied from the book

Well, ok, but why not use the project settings as I did. It is a wizard like experience, and not knowing what version of access you have? probably MUCH better to just have ONE connection string in the project settings, and thus:

You don't type in connecting strings in code! (yuk, and besides, it error prone to do so).

you get to use a connection builder as my above screen gif shows.

You have ONE spot for the connection, and thus down the road, if you change that connection string, then you not have a hodge podge of code and hard coded and hand typed connection strings. So, use the connection builder.

FYI:
Since you using vs2019, the as noted MAKE SURE you force the project to x64 cpu, since it has to match ms-access x64.

Also, while you CAN use the connection builder, you find/note/see/experience that the test connection does NOT work. So, the above connection builder is the way to go, but you find the test connection button does not work. (and the reason is that vs2019 is x32 bits, and ms-access is x64 bits. So, you HAVE to run your code to really know and see if your connection actually works.

So, while vs2019 is a x32 bit product, it is free and able to compile a project as x64 bits, and EVEN allows debugging of such projects. However, just keep in mind that the connection builder can be used, should be used as per above (settings), the "test connection" button will not work in vs2019 for a x64 bit version of access.

Regardless of the above narrative? The CPU project setting/choice here matters, since you are free to choose whatever CPU for compile, you made a choice to use ms-access x64, and thus your compiled .net software has to match that version of access CPU architecture wise.

(too bad ms-access was not built using .net, since then it could also run as ANY CPU, but it not written nor compiled in .net, so the developers did not have a "any cpu" choice when they build/compile ms-access.

So, my real lesson above??

have a good reason for making a choice - not random.

> If you know of better materials

Well, I can bet that the last 10,000 example you find with google, none will suggest using ADO in .net (a ActiveX reference).

I mean, I'm betting that good reason WHY you attempted to use a Active Data objects reference? Why of course that's what you ALWAYS did and had to do in the past!! (so that is a good reason why, EVEN if the wrong answer!!! In other words, for any choice you make? At least have a good reason for making that choice - even when it is the wrong choice, at least you were "thinking" as to why you making such a choice, and that I 100% respect, even when it the wrong choice!!!).

Comment: If you know of better materials, please let me know.

64-bits: My Access 2019 is 64-bit, and I thought that 64-bit has been around long enough to be "mature".

Connection string was copied from the book (except for the path, of course):
strMainDbConnection="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Data\CRMS.accdb" 
dbMain = New OleDbConnection(strMainDbConnection)

I do have code elsewhere that binds the DataTable to form controls, and it works well. [more later]

Comment: I added this to your example: conn.Open()
I changed your table name tglLogs to my tblUserLogEvents
da.Update(rstData) throws an error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'
I added 
Debug.Print("Insert command:" + daU.GetInsertCommand.CommandText)
which shows the SQL command as: 
INSERT INTO tblUserLogEvents (MACaddress, UserID, IPaddress, When, LoggedIn) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

One of my other attempts at a solution gave me the same error.  How can I fix this?

Comment: See my edit and comments. You don't write nor use a sql insert statement, you use a select statement, since we using a data table - which works MUCH like your past code using ADO in vb6.

Comment: That was quite a response, so I'll digest it in pieces. Also I seem to only be able to comment 500 characters at a time.  Is there a tutorial or such for StackOverflow?

Comment: The only three changes I made to your code were the .Open() method, the table name and the WHERE clause to "UserID = ""zzzzzzzzzz""" (my primary key is UserID and is SHORT TEXT of 10 characters).  Thus I did not create an INSERT INTO statement.  I think OleDbCommandBuilder did that (and GetInsertCommand.CommandText let me peek at it), but the MyNewRow assignments didn't replace the ?,?,?,?,? with actual data.  Then I believe the da.Update(rstDat) tried to execute it and choked.

Comment: Without the conn.Open() method, rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader) throws this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.'

Comment: 32/64-bit: Yes, CPU setting in VB is 64-bit to match my 64-bit Access.  I choose 64-bit because I believe it should be faster and allows bigger data.  The future is 64-bit, and somedat 32-bit will go the way of 16-bit.

Comment: Does the "test button" work in VS2022?  I originally installed VS2022 but my book's author's website said that his VBDB 2019 book was not compatible with it.  Is there anything in VS2022 that breaks VB2019 code?  That wouldn't make sense, but a lot of stuff doesn't, like extended memory function from Dos/Win3.1 to Win95 to WinNT to WinXP to Win10.

Comment: I like embedding the connection string in code.  I put in a "global" variable so it's accessible everywhere. If it works once, it always works (until MicroSoft changes things, which requires code changes anyway).  I like it because I hope this app will be in many locations for the company, connected by VPN, so that path might vary from computer to computer. The user can locate it with OpenFileDialog and the location saves to the registry.  Would I get that flexibility with the project settings wizard?

Comment: Well, with desktop software, you can get away using a global variable, but with web based software, you can't do that. Also, while it seems counter intuitive, .net does what is called connection pooling. That means in the past, it was VERY command, if not outright important to build + open one connection. Now, we let .net do that job, and it is now far better to close each connection use. That means a "using" block to close that connection, and .net will then manage this issue for you (it will keep a connection pool for you). If task at hand is to prompt/choose a file? Sure that can be global

Comment: Well, in fact, the test connection button in vs2022 would be the FIRST version of vs that would work and allow the test connection button to work against access x64. In fact, now we find that test connection will not work with access x32!!!, but should and will with access x64!.  While in general x64 code not going to run faster (since your data word sizes are larger - it costs memory bandwidth), in some cases you can benefit. And no, I can't think of much of anything in vs2022 that would change from 2019, but that of now 2022 is a x64 bit product, were as 2019 is a x32 bit product.

Comment: And yes, more then once now - you need the conn.Open() as per my edited code example. You also need to set the PK value, since that now looks to not be a autonumber column, but your PK now looks to be a value you have to set. So, that code example will require you to set the pk value for a given row you add. With a using block, you don't however have to close that connection object

Comment: However, the fact of test connection not available say when working with Access x64 (and vs2019), or now that test connection not working with vs2022 and access x32? Not a big deal, since you can still at least use the builder for that connection's. As noted, if you going to prompt the user, then you could still have the application "remember" the setting for you. (use "user" setting in that settings dialog, since those are "per user").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253514/discussion-between-bittwiddler-and-albert-d-kallal).